# Does the Monero daemon and wallet connect with other nodes by ssl or unencrypted?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, encryption

Do Monero nodes connect to each other by encrypted channels or non-encrypted? Is Monero resistant to spying by ISP, in other words can Monero use be censored in its current form?

Answer (score 11):

From my knowledge the connection is not encrypted, **but this doesn't hurt anything** because the data that is exchanged is already **public record**.

*For example: **the same information** can also be found on* [Moneroblocks](http://moneroblocks.info/)

Comment: Yes but I meant it more for ISP spying on if a user is using Monero or not. Is it censorship resistant to ISPs?

Comment: @pl55 based on that comment you should edit your question to clarify what you are asking.... but yes your ISP could tell if they know what to look for. Solutions to prevent that include a VPN and I2P

Comment: Ok thanks. Edited original question for better clarity. If elfixit doesn't respond, you may want to post an answer so I can close the question.